# Why do I need to install RSAT on Windows 8.1 for accessing Hyper-V Server 2012 R2?

Tags: hyper-v-server-2012, windows-8.1, windows

Since Windows 8.1 has Hyper-V Platform and Hyper-V Manager built in to it, if I just enable the Hyper-V Manager on my Windows 8.1 client machine I should be able to access the standalone Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 (which I'm planning to install on my 2nd machine) right?

Then why every article I found on this suggests to install RSAT on my client machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to download and install RSAT for this.

Hyper-V Manager, while technically an "RSAT technology", is shipped with Windows 8/8.1, rather than with the RSAT package.

[According to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2693643):

> Hyper-V tools are not part of Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8. They are available as part of Windows 8. You do not have to install RSAT to use these tools.

Hyper-V Manager is shipped with Windows rather than with RSAT because Windows 8/8.1 also ships with a workstation-customized version of the hypervisor, known as Client Hyper-V, which Hyper-V Manager also manages.

Comment: +1 RSAT makes sense if you're *clustering* hyper-v servers because you then need the clustering tools, but for basic hyper-v the built in tools are fine.